# Show PHP timestamp on cached page

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, timestamp

I am including a php snippet into my header banner using

```
<?php include ('/time.php'); ?>
```

here is the code I got from another SE post:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago'); // timezone 

    $weekday = date(l); // today
    // print $weekday; // Debug
    // print date("H:i"); // debug

    // Set open and closing time for each day of the week
    if ($weekday != "Saturday" || $weekday != "Sunday") {
        $open_from = "07:00";
        $open_to = "24:00";
    }

    // now check if the current time is before or after opening hours
    if (date("H:i") < $open_from || date("H:i") > $open_to ) {
        print "House: We're closed for the day.";
    }

    else {
        print "Hours: We're open!";
    }
?>
```

It works fine when viewing the time.php directly in the browser, but on the homepage it looks like the caching system is caching the last message which was generated by the file. For example it will say "We're closed" indefinitely until I purge the cached page on the server.

Must I rework this method to use AJAX instead?

Or, would a jQuery function accomplish it, or would it simply be cached also like the PHP snippet's results?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
add_filter( 'wp_headers', $headers ) function() {
    return array_merge( $headers, wp_get_nocache_headers() );
} );
```

This adds the no cache headers:

```
'Expires' => 'Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT',
'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0',
'Last-Modified'] = false,
```

to the HTTP headers to be sent.